# const provider= new ethers.provider.JsonRpcProvider('https://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/48e3dcb8dcc3420fa8c765b7c04a75f8'); TypeError:

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, nodejs

const provider= new ethers.provider.JsonRpcProvider('https://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/48e3dcb8dcc3420fa8c765b7c04a75f8');
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
I downgraded the ether version but my one js file ran and another did not.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it is `providers` in plural. So it should look like `ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(..)`.

```
const provider= new ethers.provider.JsonRpcProvider('https://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/<PRJID>');
```